# Entity Framework ... Four queries into one

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF5 and finding questions as follows:

```
context.Questions
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
  .Where(x => x.Difficulty == difficulty && x.Format == format);
```

Each Question has a field named duration with values (2, 4, 6 and 8) in minutes.

I have the following int array: { 4, 0, 1, 2 } which means:

Get 4 questions of 2 minutes, 0 of 4 minutes, 1 of 6 minutes and 2 of 8 minutes.

After .OrderBy and .Where I need to get 7 questions as mentioned.

Is there a way to do this without loading all questions or using 4 queries?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hardcoded - but you get the idea, and solves your problem explicitly.  You should be able to convert it to whatever you need from here.

```
var questions =  context.Questions .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                        .Where(x => x.Difficulty == difficulty && x.Format == format);

var selectedQuestions = questions.Where(q => q.Duration == 2).Take(questionArray[0])
    .Union(questions.Where(q => q.Duration == 4).Take(questionArray[1]))
    .Union(questions.Where(q => q.Duration == 6).Take(questionArray[2]))
    .Union(questions.Where(q => q.Duration == 8).Take(questionArray[3]));
```

Since you're never enumerating the queryable, EF will do all of these unions in sql, and get all the data in a single call.

Produced SQL:

```
SELECT [Distinct3].[C1] AS [C1],
       [Distinct3].[C2] AS [C2],
       [Distinct3].[C3] AS [C3],
       [Distinct3].[C4] AS [C4]
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT [UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C1],
                        [UnionAll3].[C2] AS [C2],
                        [UnionAll3].[C3] AS [C3],
                        [UnionAll3].[C4] AS [C4]
        FROM   (SELECT   [Distinct2].[C1] AS [C1],
                         [Distinct2].[C2] AS [C2],
                         [Distinct2].[C3] AS [C3],
                         [Distinct2].[C4] AS [C4]
                FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1],
                                          [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C2],
                                          [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C3],
                                          [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C4]
                          FROM   (SELECT   [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1],
                                           [Distinct1].[C2] AS [C2],
                                           [Distinct1].[C3] AS [C3],
                                           [Distinct1].[C4] AS [C4]
                                  FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1],
                                                            [UnionAll1].[Duration] AS [C2],
                                                            [UnionAll1].[Difficulty] AS [C3],
                                                            [UnionAll1].[Format] AS [C4]
                                            FROM   (SELECT   TOP (4) [Project1].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                                     [Project1].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                                     [Project1].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                                     [Project1].[Format] AS [Format]
                                                    FROM     (SELECT NEWID() AS [C1],
                                                                     [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                                     [Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                                     [Extent1].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                                     [Extent1].[Format] AS [Format]
                                                              FROM   [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent1]
                                                              WHERE  ([Extent1].[Difficulty] = @p__linq__0)
                                                                     AND ([Extent1].[Format] = @p__linq__1)
                                                                     AND (2 = [Extent1].[Duration])) AS [Project1]
                                                    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
                                                    UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT   TOP (0) [Project3].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                                     [Project3].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                                     [Project3].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                                     [Project3].[Format] AS [Format]
                                                    FROM     (SELECT NEWID() AS [C1],
                                                                     [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                                     [Extent2].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                                     [Extent2].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                                     [Extent2].[Format] AS [Format]
                                                              FROM   [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent2]
                                                              WHERE  ([Extent2].[Difficulty] = @p__linq__2)
                                                                     AND ([Extent2].[Format] = @p__linq__3)
                                                                     AND (4 = [Extent2].[Duration])) AS [Project3]
                                                    ORDER BY [Project3].[C1] ASC) AS [UnionAll1]) AS [Distinct1]
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT   TOP (1) [Project7].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                   [Project7].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                   [Project7].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                   [Project7].[Format] AS [Format]
                                  FROM     (SELECT NEWID() AS [C1],
                                                   [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id],
                                                   [Extent3].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                                   [Extent3].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                                   [Extent3].[Format] AS [Format]
                                            FROM   [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent3]
                                            WHERE  ([Extent3].[Difficulty] = @p__linq__4)
                                                   AND ([Extent3].[Format] = @p__linq__5)
                                                   AND (6 = [Extent3].[Duration])) AS [Project7]
                                  ORDER BY [Project7].[C1] ASC) AS [UnionAll2]) AS [Distinct2]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT   TOP (2) [Project11].[Id] AS [Id],
                                 [Project11].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                 [Project11].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                 [Project11].[Format] AS [Format]
                FROM     (SELECT NEWID() AS [C1],
                                 [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id],
                                 [Extent4].[Duration] AS [Duration],
                                 [Extent4].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty],
                                 [Extent4].[Format] AS [Format]
                          FROM   [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent4]
                          WHERE  ([Extent4].[Difficulty] = @p__linq__6)
                                 AND ([Extent4].[Format] = @p__linq__7)
                                 AND (8 = [Extent4].[Duration])) AS [Project11]
                ORDER BY [Project11].[C1] ASC) AS [UnionAll3]) AS [Distinct3];
```

Comment: Is this to convince the OP he better use 4 separate queries after all? :)

Comment: I'll leave that up to him... but the SQL does get kinda outta hand fast :)

Comment: In fact there are 8 duration so I will have 8 queries. Don't you think have 8 queries will be heavy? But at the same time that generated SQL seems to big. Should I use raw SQL and send it through EF?

Comment: Honestly.. it depends - how beefy is your sql server?  How big is your database? The query is lonnnggg.. but if it only takes a few seconds to execute I wouldn't worry about it. I'd try it and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get 4 (or max of the array) questions of each type and do the filtering on the client? With 16 results it should be cheap - you can use linq grouping to group them by minutes and then it should be easy. Another interesting point here is ordering... If you have more than 4 questions but you always order them when selecting would you ever see any other questions that just first 4?

Comment: I am ordering by Guid.NewGuid which does a random ordering ... So I never get the same values.

Answer (score 0):

My query is a little bit more complex. Basically, I ended up with the following:

```
context.Questions
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
  .Where(x =>
    x.AccessLevel >= accessLevel &&
    x.Enabled == true &&
    x.QuestionFormat == questionFormat
    x.Theme.Id == themeId
  )
  .Select(x => new {
    Answers = x.Answers.Select(y => new {
      Correct = y.Correct,
      Packs = y.Packs.SelectMany(z => z.Files, (z, v) => new {
        Id = z.Id,
        File = new { Key = v.Key, Mime = v.Mime }
      }),
      Text = y.Text
    }),
    Duration = x.Duration,
    Note = x.Note,
    Text = x.Text,
    Packs = x.Packs.SelectMany(y => y.Files, (y, z) => new {
      Id = y.Id,
      File = new { Key = z.Key, Mime = z.Mime }
    })
   })
   .GroupBy(x => x.Duration);
```

So I am ordering the questions randomly and filtering them.

Then I get, for each question, its answers ...

Each question and answer have some files associated with them.

I have all files in one table. This is why I have Packs and Files in my query.

I am only loading the Files Keys and Mimes. Not the data.

So you suggestion is to get all questions grouped by time, right?

In fact, after do the AccessLevel / Enabled / QuestionFormat / Theme filtering I will never have so many questions ...

So I can group them by Duration as I did in the end of this query.

What would be a fast way to take the number of questions of each duration according to the array I posted in the beginning?

Thank You,
Miguel